# Wordpress get_template_directory_uri() and bloginfo('template_directory') return different results with HTTPS

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl, https, themes

I'm migrating a current `WordPress 4.7.3` site to become full `SSL` and when I log into the site using `https://` prefix the function calls to `get_template_directory_uri()` and `bloginfo('template_directory')` will skip the theme part of the path.

An example code line that I'm able to notice is this:

```
wp_enqueue_style('fancybox', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css', false, null);
```

Another example code line would be this:

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/img/myimg.png" class="pull-left img-responsive"/>
```

This is the current working result sample excerpts in the order they appear on the result source code if I request the page with `http://example.com`

```
...
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/assets/css/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css">
...
<img src="http://example.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/assets/img/myimg.png" class="pull-left img-responsive"/>
...
```

This is then the same approach applied to the result calling with `https://example.com`

```
...
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://example.com/assets/css/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css">
...
<img src="https://example.com/assets/img/myimg.png" class="pull-left img-responsive"/>
...
```

I've recently migrated other sites with same WP version and legacy templates that use the same functions and they just work so that's why I'm intrigued if this is by any chance a specific `wp_option` or other setting that would be causing this behavior that I'm not being able to figure out.

For clarity, both `siteurl` and `home` are set to `https://example.com` and, of course, this is not the actual domain name. This is a clean WP install that has no changes on it's core, only a theme and couple plugins (askimet, S3 uploads) which shouldn't conflict.

Any clues on why the `/wp-content/themes/mytheme` is been skipped on the `https://` call?

Comment: Just to be clear, you replaced `get_template_directory_uri()` with `bloginfo` right?

Comment: @ChinLeung I did not replace. Above I mention only one case. I see other cases with `bloginfo` that return same pattern like `<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/img/image.png" class="pull-left img-responsive"/>` and that's why i mention both functions.

Comment: @ChinLeung I've edited the question trying to get a better clarity on the scenario. Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It ends up that this has been happening due to a couple of configurations on the theme:

```
add_theme_support('root-relative-urls');    // Enable relative URLs
add_theme_support('rewrites');              // Enable URL rewrites
```

After removing that I was able to get the expected result and the site now works with SSL using `https://`.

In order to find that, I had to compare every file from other templates that work and by trial and errors got to this.

Hope it helps someone in the future not to get too much time wasted on a similar issue!

Comment: Good to know! Nice find :)

Answer (score 0):

If you replace `get_template_directory_uri()` with `bloginfo('template_directory')`, it's normal that you're getting the path without the theme path because the function [bloginfo](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/bloginfo/) doesn't return any value, it simply [echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) the value. Side node, if you view the page source, you should probably see somewhere in the DOM:

```
https://example.com/example.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme
```

Therefore, when you enqueue the style, it's only enqueuing `'/assets/css/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css'`.

What you want is [get_bloginfo](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_bloginfo/) instead which will return the value instead of echo:

```
wp_enqueue_style('fancybox', get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/assets/css/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css', false, null);
```

Comment: The same functions are used in other themes/sites and it works fine with `https`. I'm first trying not to change the theme and see if there is some specifics on this WP settings/setup causing this weird behavior before I start hacking the theme out.